# I cant install my published app script in the chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, chrome-web-store

I have a working apps script that works perfectly when I run it as a web app 'Test' and 'current web url'.  I uploaded it to the Chrome Web Store and everything looks good.  I then try to install it and I get an error.

Could not add application "myappname" because it conflicts with "Google Apps Script".

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can't install it because you already have a version of it installed. The Web App version of it. So when it tries to install it, its conflicting with your google-app-script version of the App you created.

Comment: Tulio,  Thanks for the reply.  What you are saying is making sense but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.  I went into the script and and clicked on the 'disable web app' link.  I then went to the webstore 'Add to chrome page' and clicked on the 'visit website' button and the app didn't come up.  I went ahead and did another 'deploy as Web App' and now it works but cant be installed.  I'm hoping you can help me understand the error in my ways.